# Using executables/programs installed in vagrant vm from the host

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-plugin, vagrant-provision

Is it possible to use a software/program (e.g. java/ maven) installed in vagrant vm from the host machine? Like placing the executable in the synced folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount an external folder(host machine) on Vagrant.

While bringing vagrant up you can use option "-v" and provide source path and target path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I want to use softwares installed on the vagrant vm from the host. I think the other way round you thought.

Comment: Inside vagrant what OS you have installed? or you can see this link and get some help # http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html